# Serilog : creating Multiple log files when calling a wcf service

Tags: wcf, serilog

I have serilog parameters described in web.config as below:

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Debug" />
 <add key="serilog:using:RollingFile" value="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" />
 <add key="serilog:write-to:File.rollingInterval" value="Day"/>
 <add key="serilog:write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat" value="c:\temp\log.txt" />  
</appSettings>
```

In my wcf service, code is as below

```
public class CalculateService : ICalculateService
{
    private Logger _logger;

    public CalculateService()
    {            
           _logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
            .CreateLogger();
           _logger.Debug("calling constructor");
    }

}
```

When I'm calling this service from the Console application, a separate log file is created each time. I want to initialize log only once and want to create a new log file each day.

Comment: Logging initialization should not be done in actual service - it should be done in the startup code (main, app_start etc) (though, as a hack, you could use a static constructor)

Comment: @RubenBartelink I found two working solutions for this:   
1. Static Constructor
2. InstanceContextMode.Single
With the above solutions, I'm able to fix the issue. 
I wanted to know the startup of my WCF service as I couldn't find the Startup code for my WCF service as it has no global.asax file

Comment: How to do that with WCF depends on exactly how you are hosting and is a very separate question (you could ask another question, providing details as to what versions of things you have, what Main (if you have one) looks like etc). Hacking the instancing mode is not going to be a good solution, and if you have >1 service then static ctor in one is not good either. Best to find out how to solve the problem (how do I do one time init in my WCF host) properly as having a static ctor in each Service call a central log init boostrap is also going to be messy and error prone.